# How do you supress automatic update restart prompt?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

So, I made a bunch of my users mad today when they all the sudden couldn't get their email, printers, or network shares because I inadvertently restarted our Exchange server while working on some changes.  How did it happen?  Automatic updates insisted on poping up with a window to restart at wrong place at the wrong time.  I went to click a user with Active Directory, and there popped up the restart message just as soon as I clicked.

I've done ok to avoid the prompt in the past, but now I'm ready to do something about.  **Is there a way to suppress the popup window asking to restart?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "servers" should be in a separate OU. This OU should have a GPO linked or inherited to it that governs the Windows Update settings for the box. Among these settings in the ADM template are ones that suppress most of these Windows.